# Phonegap and other native programming languages

Tags: phonegap-build, mobile-application

I am building a mobile app for a community, Although most of the target group use android os, however some of them use  IOS, windows and blackberry. Almost all the leaders use IOS. Now, the time to present this mobile app is limited. I have finished building the mobile app in native android platform.

I have heard of phone gab, which helps you build an app for all platforms.  Please I am now confuse, should  I build the app in all the native languages or use phone gap?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge phonegap is  better if you are going to make application for multiple platform.In phonegap by using javascript,jquery,css n html you can write code.and by using phonegap you can directly convert it into applications for  Android,IOS, windows and blackberry platforms.

Comment: @NewBle  If you know how to write webpages, then phonegap can be helpful and get your product to your customers sooner, but it could also be a headache. Here is the [Phonegap FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the result you want. Native and hybrid apps generally don't behave the same way on devices.
If you already have an existing Android app, you should consider trying other crossplatform development tools that use source code in Java instead of HTML5, and produce native apps instead of hybrid ones. NeoMAD could be a good candidate, the API is very close to Android and you can quickly convert existing Android source code into crossplatform code.